# setting created checkbox as checked not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

thanks for helping...
I'm creating a series of html elements in javascript, including checkboxes. I want to go ahead and mark one of the checkboxes by default. I cannot get the 'checked' property to exist using either pure javascript (checkbox.checked = true;) or jquery library (see below). See my example, thank you - EDIT: The pure jQuery solution does work, but I'm having trouble with a javascript solution. Subsequent checkbox elements seem to inhibit the 'checked' attribute on prior ones. See this fiddle for an example...[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/J6gZt/)

```
function createToolbarElements(){
        //------topbar-------------
        var topbar = document.getElementById("topbar");
        topbar.innerHTML = "ZONE: ";

        //zone set
        ART.regions.unshift("All");
        ART.regions.push("osj");
        var numRegions = ART.regions.length;
        var region;
        for(i=0; i<numRegions; i+=1){
            region = ART.regions[i];
            var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
            checkbox.type = "checkbox";
            checkbox.name = region;
            checkbox.value = region;
            checkbox.id = "zone"+region;
            if(region === "All"){
                $("#zoneAll").prop("checked", true);
            }
            topbar.appendChild(checkbox);
            var label = document.createElement('label')
            label.htmlFor = region;
            label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(region));
            topbar.appendChild(label);
        }
}
```

here's the HTML:

```
    <div id="topbar" style="z-index: 2; position:absolute; height: 24px; padding: 4px;
    background-color: #DDD; color:#111;  font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    font-size:10pt; line-height:1.2">
    </div>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo (a missing `#`).


Comment: If you know which checkbox you want to check, why not wait until the end of the loop and call `$("#zoneAll").prop("checked", true);` or even `document.getElementById('zoneAll').checked = true` then instead of checking each iteration?

Comment: I tried both suggestions by Jason P, with no luck.

Comment: Could you please post your HTML?

Comment: I've added html... The pure jQuery solution does work, but I'm having trouble with a javascript solution. Subsequent checkbox elements seem to inhibit the 'checked' attribute on prior ones. See this fiddle for an example... [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J6gZt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just stick with jQuery, as you're using it anyway :

```
function createToolbarElements(){
        $('#topbar').html('ZONE: ');

        ART.regions.unshift('All');
        ART.regions.push('osj');

    var numRegions = ART.regions.length,
        region     = null;

    for(i=0; i<numRegions; i++){
        region = ART.regions[i];

        $('<input />', {
            type : 'checkbox',
            name : region,
            value: region,
            id   : 'zone' + region,
            checked: region == 'All'
        }).appendTo('#topbar');

        $('<label />', {
            'for': 'zone' + region,
            text : region
        }).appendTo('#topbar');
    }
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UWUUU/3/)

or not use jQuery at all, and just do:

```
checkbox.checked = region === "All";
```

Note that the element you're trying to grab from the DOM, `$("#zoneAll")` is actually appended to the DOM after you're trying to get it, so doing it that way will always fail as the element doesn't exist when you're trying to access it.

Comment: I tried reversing those instructions - still didn't have a checked attribute.

Comment: Did you check out the fiddle, it clearly works just fine as the checkboxes are checked ?

Comment: Yes, I just did. I got it to work, thank you. I'm new to jQuery as of today. I still don't understand why setting the checked attribute in the ways I tried did not work, though. I was not able to set the checked value at all.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because your selector would fail to get the element, as it wasn't appended when you where trying to access it, so it would always fail.

Comment: I was thinking that too, but I switched the append statement ahead of it, and it doesn't work. And I'm able to set other things, like name, value, type. I tried your non-jQuery suggestion as well, but didn't work...     `var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
                checkbox.type = "checkbox";
                checkbox.name = region;
                checkbox.value = region;
                checkbox.id = "zone"+region;
                
                topbar.appendChild(checkbox);
                checkbox.checked = region==="All";`

Comment: When setting the checked property, you can actually do it before appending the element, just like you would any other property -> http://jsfiddle.net/ZZMUR/ , the issue isn't setting the property, it's setting the property on `$('#zoneAll')` which is an empty collection when the element does not yes exist in the DOM.

Comment: Apologies - the site won't let me use the chat function. Thanks for the other fiddle, and it makes perfect sense, and it's the first thing I tried, but something in my program isn't letting it work. Regarding, the point about $('#zoneAll'), at what point does it exist in the DOM? I did try that statement after appending the element.

Comment: I think this shows the crux of my problem -- when I go on to make other checkbox elements, it seems to corrupt previous ones... [see this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J6gZt/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$("#zoneAll").prop("checked", true);
```

Make sure your selector works. I assume you're trying to select by the ID `zoneAll`, in which case you need to use `$('#zoneAll')`. This will work in the case that your node looks like this in your HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="zoneAll"></input>
```

EDIT: I originally said to use `attr()`, which was horrendously badwrong. After some Google-Fu, `prop()` is indeed the way to go.

Comment: +1 for the missing `#`, -1 for suggesting to use `.attr()` over `.prop()`.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I'm stuck in the older days of jQuery. Thanks for the insight into `prop()`.

Comment: The selector is correct. I've matched the resulting id ('zoneAll') to what I've typed, including with the '#' symbol $('#zoneAll').

Answer (score 1):

You need `#` to select an element by `id`.

```
$("#zoneAll")
```